# C pointers in Windows sockets

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, winsock

I'm starting with sockets on Windows in C, and I'm trying to understand the use of pointers in C and get a clear idea of why some variables are pointers.

In this code:

```c
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;
unsigned short ServPort;
char *ServIP;
WSADATA wsaData;

ServIP = "192.168.1.6";
ServPort = 50005;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) {
    exit(1);
}

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ServIP);
ServAddr.sin_port = htons(ServPort);
```

**1. Why is `ServIP` a pointer and `ServPort` is not?**

```c
unsigned short ServPort;
char *ServIP;`

ServIP = "192.168.1.6";

ServPort = 50005;
```

---

**2. Are these variables pointers?**

```c
struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;

WSADATA wsaData;
```

Comment: ServAddr is a struct, but memset needs a pointer to the struct to clear it.  ServIP is declared a pointer, but should be a string (an array of char) char ServIP[32] = "192.168.1.6"; will initialize it. ServPort is a plain unsigned short.

Comment: In C, it is normal to pass strings to functions not by value, but rather by reference, by passing a pointer to the first element of the string. That way, it is not necessary to always copy the entire string when passing it to a fucntion. The port number is passed by value (i.e. a simple copy of the value is passed), because it is a simple integer value. `"192.168.1.6"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), which [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the string literal.

Answer (score 3):

> **1. Why is `ServIP` a pointer and `ServPort` is not?**

`ServIP` is a `char *` because that's the type that substantially all C functions require for handling strings.  The value is actually a pointer to the first `char` of the string, which continues up to and including the first `char` with value 0.

`ServPort` is not a pointer because there is no reason for it to be one.  `unsigned short` is the type required for this variable's purpose.

The question makes me wonder whether you are among those who take pointer-ness to be analogous to a type qualifier, such as `const`, that produces a different variant of a base type.  **This is not the case at all.**  Pointer types are completely separate types from their pointed-to types.  They generally have different size and representation, and are in no way interchangeable with their pointed-to type.<sup>*</sup>  Thus, you use pointers for things that require pointers and not for things that require non-pointers.

> **2. Are these variables pointers?**
>
> ```
> struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;
> ```

`struct sockaddr_in` is definitely a structure type, not a pointer type.  We know this from the presence of the `struct` keyword and the absence of `*` from the type name, together.  `ServAddr` therefore is not a pointer.

> ```
> WSADATA wsaData;
> ```

It is not immediately apparent from the name `WSADATA` whether that is a pointer type.  It is a macro or typedef name that obscures the details (in fact the latter).  But if we look it up, we can find [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-wsadata) pretty easily, and that reveals that `WSADATA` is a structure type, not a pointer type.  So `wsaData` is not a pointer.

---

<sup>*</sup> With some exceptions related to type `void *`, which I'm glossing over for the sake of simplicity.